# Unable to use Charts framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I installed [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) via cocoapods to an Xcode project but I get the following errors on building it: 'No such module Charts' and 'ChartPlatform.swift : Method does not override any method from its superclass'. 
I made sure to uncomment 'use_frameworks', in the podfile and open the project using the xcworkspace file. Not sure where I went wrong. I've always installed pods the same way and haven't had problems till today.
How can I fix this?

Comment: is you project is an objective-c project?

Comment: 1. Is your project in objective-c or swift
2. Can you tell us setting options in 

Product Module Name : myproject
Defines Module : YES
Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES
Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
Objective-C Bridging Header : $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem because I was using an older version of Xcode. The Charts framework only works with Xcode 8 and swift versions 2.3 or 3.0. Try updating and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed Charts.framework from Embedded Binaries and then added again rebuild the project (Cmd+B) the error has gone.

[image: Remove and add again]